# Test for answers in an IF block

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help (again).  New to python, but how do I test for both "yes" and "y" in the same if block?

[image: Code block showing logic switches for both 'yes' and 'y']

In shell I would just do:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read -r -n 1 -p $'Would you like to continue? [y/n]\n\n--> ' ANSWER
case "$ANSWER" in
    Y|y)
        echo -en "\n\nContinue\n"
        ;;
    N|n)
        echo -en "\n\nStop\n"
        ;;
    *)
        echo -en "\n\nERROR\n"
        ;;
esac
```

I'm still new to Python3 (*well, Python in general*) that I don't know how to do this, and I've tried to google it, but I don't really understand what I'm actually asking for. I'm assuming it'll be very simple like BASH, but the answers I get on google seem overtly complex.

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your code as text, not an image of text.

Comment: Please include code as a [formatted code block](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

```
response = input('Would like to …?').lower()

if response == 'y' or response == 'yes':
    …
```

Or

```
if response in ['y', 'yes']:
    …
```

Note that it’s not necessary to call `str` — your object is already a string.